# ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize on topic coherence

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-integer, python-itertools, topic-modeling

im following this tutorials https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluate-topic-model-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-7d57484bb5d0 and find problem. so my purpose on this code to make iterate it over the range of topics, alpha, and beta parameter values. so I can determine the optimal number of topics from the coherence score generated by alpha and beta

```
def compute_coherence_values(corpus, dictionary, k, a, b):

lda_model = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus,
                                       id2word=id2word,
                                       num_topics=10, 
                                       random_state=100,
                                       chunksize=100,
                                       passes=10,
                                       alpha=a,
                                       eta=b,
                                       per_word_topics=True)

coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')

return coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
```

and then

```
import numpy as np
import tqdm
grid = {}
grid['Validation_Set'] = {}
# Topics range
min_topics = 2
max_topics = 11
step_size = 1
topics_range = range(min_topics, max_topics, step_size)
# Alpha parameter
alpha = list(np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.3))
alpha.append('symmetric')
alpha.append('asymmetric')
# Beta parameter
beta = list(np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.3))
beta.append('symmetric')
# Validation sets
num_of_docs = len(corpus)
corpus_sets = [# gensim.utils.ClippedCorpus(corpus, num_of_docs*0.25), 
               # gensim.utils.ClippedCorpus(corpus, num_of_docs*0.5), 
               gensim.utils.ClippedCorpus(corpus, num_of_docs*0.75), 
               corpus]
corpus_title = ['75% Corpus', '100% Corpus']
model_results = {'Validation_Set': [],
                 'Topics': [],
                 'Alpha': [],
                 'Beta': [],
                 'Coherence': []
                }
# Can take a long time to run
if 1 == 1:
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=540)

    # iterate through validation corpuses
    for i in range(len(corpus_sets)):
        # iterate through number of topics
        for k in topics_range:
            # iterate through alpha values
            for a in alpha:
                # iterare through beta values
                for b in beta:
                    # get the coherence score for the given parameters
                    cv = compute_coherence_values(corpus=corpus_sets[i], dictionary=id2word, 
                                                  k=k, a=a, b=b)
                    # Save the model results
                    model_results['Validation_Set'].append(corpus_title[i])
                    model_results['Topics'].append(k)
                    model_results['Alpha'].append(a)
                    model_results['Beta'].append(b)
                    model_results['Coherence'].append(cv)

                    pbar.update(1)
    pd.DataFrame(model_results).to_csv('lda_tuning_results.csv', index=False)
    pbar.close()
```

come out this error **ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.**

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluate-topic-model-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-7d57484bb5d0 im following this tutorials

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback; you never call `islice` here, so we have *no* idea where to begin looking for the problem. Ideally try to narrow this to a [MCVE].

Comment: My deep insight is that the error message is right. If you can't find where it's happening, look for a debugger that can break on exceptions?

Answer (score 31):

took me forever to figure this out but this is what you need to change where you have num_of_doc*.075 in the corpus_set change it to **int(num_of_docs*0.75)** and it will run. it will take a long time but it will get rid of the error